# passing php string with multiple lines to a javascript function/variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm working on someone else's website and it has a very stupid logic!
Anyway, there is a php variable which contains a string which comes from database.

```
$x = ' aaaa
bbb

ccc


gggg ';
```

and I need to feed this string to a javascript function:

```
<script>

var x = "<?php echo $x ; ?>";
some_function(x);

</script>
```

As you know I end up with an error because a javascript variable cannot contain multiple lines without joining them together like this:

```
var x = ' i '+
        ' have '+
        ' different lines';
```

How can I do this? It doesn't matter if it removes the lines or formats it properly, I just want to get rid of this error.

Comment: You should update your question with the desired output. Do you want it to break it up into multiple lines like your bottom example or do you want it condensed into one line like "aaaa bbb ccc gggg" or do you want it like a text box to safely read the multi line no matter what the content is?

Comment: This depends on what you deem to be an acceptable string input format to the javascript function. Do you need to maintain all that whitespace?

Comment: @KaiQing first to options !

Comment: @MikeBrant yes , it doesn't matter if i loose lines but i need white spaces so it would be readable

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pass the string into [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) to properly escape it. If you're outputting to an HTML document, make sure to pass `JSON_HEX_TAG` as part of the options, to escape `<` and `>` and prevent a malicious user from ending your `</script>` tags early and introducing an XSS exploit.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
var JsString = "<?php 
echo str_replace(array("\n","\r","\r\n"),'','YOUR 
MULTI LINE 
STRING');?>";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *absolutely* have to do this, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in JavaScript to side-step this issue. They can be multiline, so you can have

```php
<script>

var x = `<?php echo $x ; ?>`;
some_function(x);

</script>
```

This will produce the following JavaScript code:

```js
var x = ` aaaa
bbb

ccc


gggg `;

some_function(x);

function some_function(x) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Something to watch out for is that template literals can have code in them and will be evaluated if placed inside `${}`. So, if your PHP code produces such a string but you require it to be shown literally, then you might have a problem:

```js
var x = `hello ${1 + 1}`;
var y = "hello ${1 + 1}";

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

This can be especially dangerous if your PHP code happens to produce something that JavaScript can interpret as a variable name:

```js
var x = `hello ${y}`; //error - there is no variable `t`
```

With all this said, it is better to avoid programmatically generating source code, since it's error prone. It's better to use AJAX to transfer the data safely:

[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

[How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

Convert it into a string with the proper escape characters before printing it to the js.