# ' ' string literal contains an unescaped line break Error

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a text in $faq['content']; and when i echo $faq['content'] this error is displayed in browser console:

```
' ' string literal contains an unescaped line break Error
```

My code:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
$(".opencxbody").html('<div style="max-height:400px; overflow-y: scroll;"> <?php echo $faq['content']; ?></div>');
}, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like `echo $faq['content']` has newlines. So you're producing invalid JavaScript code, as you cannot have multiline string literals.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes thats true. $faq['content'] has newlines. have can i solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing php string with multiple lines to a javascript function/variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660072/passing-php-string-with-multiple-lines-to-a-javascript-function-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Please try again.

```js
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
            let data = "<div style='max-height:400px; overflow-y: scroll;'>";
                data += "<?=$sss?>";
                data += "</div>";
            $(".opencxbody").html(data);
        }, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: @Farid i am so sorry, I forgot to add **quotes**, I _edited my answer_, would you please try again?

Comment: SyntaxError: "" string literal contains an unescaped line break

Comment: <?=$sss?> Can you write the incoming data here?